# framework installation

Tags: package-management, software-installation

I want to install some framework on ubuntu 20.04. I want to install it using package manager.
The question is that, if install it using package manager then it maybe be store in **/root** partition (it maybe wrong because I am very new in Linux platform). But, I want to keep the all installation file in **/home** partition. There are any way to do that?

Comment: It may depend on the package, but generally, software is installed *system-wide*, meaning, in fixed places such as `/usr` and `/var/lib` and therefore accessible to everyone. No software is usually installed in `/root`. However, some software is intended to be installed on a per-user basis. This kind will usually be installed in `/home/username`.

Comment: It would be helpful if you listed the specific packages.

Comment: @Jos yes you are right. But I know **/usr** is the sub folder of **/root**. But, don't want to use the **/root** space. I want to store it on **/home** partition. Is it possible?

Comment: Again that depends on your package, and you haven't told us which package you want to install. And `/usr` is not a subfolder of `/root `, it is a subfolder of `/`.

Comment: @Jos, I am very sorry because I thought **/** and **/root** is the same folder. Actually I mixup it with **root** partition and **/root** folder.  I want to install nodejs package. Okay tell me another thing. Can I extain **root** partition later  and shrink **home** partition without losing any documents ?

Comment: Node.js is one of those packages that can only be installed system-wide. Regarding shrinking and extending partitions, please ask another question on this site and put in a screenshot of your disk(s) made with Gparted.

Comment: @Jos Thank a lot